# Navigate Up with Actionbar Compat

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

Following developers guide to set the app icon as up button, I done these steps to achieve this:

In the Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.configuration);

    /**Enable app icon as Up button on ActionBar*/
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

In the Manifest:

```
<activity 
    android:name="com.example.Configuration"
    android:label="@string/config_title"          
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.MainActivity" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support API level 7+ -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

But still doesn't make the up function.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write this in your activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.config_screen);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    }

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        try {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                Intent in= new Intent(Configuration.this,
                        MainACtivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("MainActivity - onOptionsItemSelected ", ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: It's a nice approach. But if I do this, every time I go back, what I'm really doing is opening a new activity. So, if for example I go to `Configuration` and go back using this up button, if I do this for 3 times, when I close my app I would have other 3 apps opened

Comment: What you want to achieve with Navigate Up functionality ?

Comment: I have `MainActivity[A]` and `Configuration` activity `[B]`. I have **Up** option just on `Configuration`, so what I need is just implement the go **Up** functionality to go back from `[B]` to `[A]`